# Group by clause based on conditions on columns

Tags: sql, group-by

The Dataset,

```
A   B   T2      Percentage
11  12  8.568   54.70737913
11  12  10.643  4.071246819
11  12  15.933  0.254452926
11  12  17.151  10.6870229
11  12  20.339  20.10178117
11  12  21.25   10.17811705
```

I want to display one record based on condition on percentage column.
If the percentage is greater than 40 then display the corresponding T2 value that is 8.568 else display the minimum value of column T2.

So basically if there is at least one percentage value which is greater than 40 then we have to display the corresponding value of column T2 else if there are no percentage value which is greater than 40 the  display minimum value of t2.

Comment: Are `A` and `B` relevant here?  Desired results *as a text table* are usually helpful.  What if two rows have a percentage over 40?  And tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Yes A and B are relevant basically for the column A and B I need one output based on the condition. If we have 2 records which are greater than 40 then we have to consider the value which is greater. Hope I have answered.

Comment: Does `Percentage` column is calculated in `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Yes, Percentage is calculated in select statement.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want one row per `a`/`b` value that meets your conditions.  For this purpose, `row_number()` seems appropriate:

```
select a, b,
       coalesce( max(case when percentage
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a, b
                                order by (case when percentage > 40 then percentage else 0 end) desc,
                                         t2
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want *all* values above 40 for a given combination, then use `rank()` and some tweaked logic:

```
select a, b,
       coalesce( max(case when percentage
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by a, b
                          order by (case when percentage > 40 then 1 else 2 end),
                                   (case when percentage <= 40 then t2 end)
                        ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  This will also return duplicates if you have duplicate minimum values.  It is not clear if this is desirable -- or even if you really want duplicates for values above 40.

Comment: Gordon, please see my comment to the question and OP's answer.